# Creating database in Netbeans for Java web application

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jdialog

I have a Jdialog which contains JTextFields and a Save button.How do I create a database table which stores `ProjectId`, `ProjectName` and `Description` and store them locally?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this you could use SQLite and the relevant JDBC driver. Here'e a tutorial which will help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm

SQLite allows you to create a local database on the file system, so you won't need a database server to host it.

Answer (score 0):

[NetBeans Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) or 
[Derby Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html)

There are two tutorials to add a database to you project in NetBeans.